# PHP Query Random

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have succeed to randomize my quiz, but the problem I facing right now is that there are certain question display again even after the have been answered. I also have a problem of limiting question that is going to be retrieved from the database. I want to make question being random shown only one time in the quiz and only select 5 question from the database as an example.

```
$singleSql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");    
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($singleSql)) 
    {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $thisQuestion = $row['question'];
        $question_id = $row['question_id'];
        $q = '<h2>'.$thisQuestion.'</h2>';


        $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answers where question_id = '$question_id' ORDER BY rand()");
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
        {
            $answer = $row2['answer'];  
            $correct = $row2['correct'];                
            $answers .= 
            '<label style="cursor:pointer;"><input type="radio" name="rads" value="'.$correct.'">'.$answer.'</label>
            <input type="hidden" id="qid" value="'.$id.'" name="qid"><br /><br />';
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should add column of status and and change it after that particular question is answered

Answer (score 1):

use `join`  .no need of two different query

```
SELECT * FROM questions q join answers a
on q.question_id=a.question_id
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

We need to select random 5 rows from questions that not persist in answers.

```
SELECT questions.* FROM questions
LEFT JOIN answers ON questions.id=answers.question_id
WHERE answers.question_id IS NULL
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: if i use this query, it means that i dont have to declare for table answer like i have done in my code right?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your first question! Code in my answer is wrong :) If you want to get 5 random different questions, just use  `LIMIT 5` instead of  `LIMIT 1` in you $singleSql. So you get array of 5 guestions at once.

Comment: im sorry, but after i change the LIMIT 1 to LIMIT 5, it just increase the number of my answer on my quiz.

Comment: I think, you should store already answered questions id's somewhere (in user cookies or in the another table with user session id) and use it in `$singleSql` `SELECT * FROM questions WHERE questions.id NOT IN ( id list separated by comma) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use "SEED" for solve your problem.

http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/rand.php

Answer (score 0):

To prevent from getting again, you have to use `NOT IN` Clause and use the array variable inside to check it. Put question ID each time into array under loop and then run query based upon condition. Like:

```
$ArrVar=array();
```

loop starts here

```
SELECT * FROM questions Where QuestionID NOT IN ($ArrVar) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"
```

Assign question ID to array variable as:

```
 $ArrVar[$ind] = $row['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make an array of unique random id's in php and pass that array to fetch the questions, and yes joining the questions and answers table would save your one DB query.

```
$arr = [];
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    $a = rand(min_id,max_id);        
    if(!in_array($a,$arr)){
       $arr[] = $a;
    }
}
```

and your sql1 statement would be something like following::

> $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id IN ".$arr);

this should solve your both questions i.e. not repeating the question and taking  your test for 5 questions